# Deployment of PersistenceUnit failed on wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, wildfly

after migration my app to wildfly8.2 from glassfish4, have this error.

```
16:36:21,298 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence.server] (EJB default - 1) Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: TopLink:Name=Development-vfs_/C_/Wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/fepa-ear.ear/fepa-ejb-1.0.0.jar/_fepaPU,Type=Configuration
16:36:21,298 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence.server] (EJB default - 1) Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: TopLink:Name=Session(vfs_/C_/Wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/fepa-ear.ear/fepa-ejb-1.0.0.jar/_fepaPU)
16:36:21,299 INFO  [org.eclipse.persistence.connection] (EJB default - 1) disconnect
16:36:21,299 INFO  [org.eclipse.persistence.connection] (EJB default - 1) vfs:/C:/Wildfly/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/fepa-ear.ear/fepa-ejb-1.0.0.jar/_fepaPU logout successful
16:36:21,323 FATAL [org.eclipse.persistence.ejb] (EJB default - 1) 
16:36:21,333 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ConfigurationBean for method public boolean it.myCompany.fepa.domain.session.ConfigurationBean.valid(): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [fepaPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: it.myCompany.fepa.domain.BaseModel.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/persistence/internal/descriptors/PersistenceObject;)V
```

same code work on glassfish.

Comment: Looks like an issue with weaving.  Are you able to try statically weaving your jars before deploying?  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Comment: Looking further, looks like a bug with a fix: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241821?start=45&tstart=0

Comment: @Chris, jars deployment i think completed. previous line of log is JBAS018559: Deployed "fepa-ear.ear" (runtime-name : "fepa-ear.ear"). this app contains one war and many jar. war is web app and work, jar contains bean with timer and this fail and produces this error. war use jar bean and work. only timer bean crash.

Comment: Solved! @Chris tip correct! thanks